# Having an issue running an Arduino sketch

Tags: arduino-uno

I just got my USB host shield attached to my Arduino Uno, opened the program sketch for `USBDESC.ino` and I'm getting an error. It says "usbhub.h not found". It won't compile. How did I go wrong?

I am using the Mac version of the Arduino IDE and downloaded the USB host shield Master v 2.0 file directly into /Arduino/java/examples. This was how I have added every previous library download. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: is that file in the arduino path? did you search for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you came up with that location as the right place to put libraries. It is wrong. Oh so very wrong.

Libraries go in `~/Documents/Arduino/libraries` as stated in [the first hit for "arduino macos libraries" on Google](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-all-about-arduino-libraries-install-use/installing-a-library-on-mac-osx).

Comment: ok that worked, but now I just get a garbled output from running the script